# Qt moving slots function to another cpp file

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator, slots

I have a Qt project made by Qt creator.
I let the creator itself generate a private slots function fx. on_pushbutton_clicked().
This function is declared in header, the function itself is in the cpp file created by the Qt creator.
When I move the function from cpp file generated by Qt creator to another cpp file (it is added in the project, it has the same includes as the generated cpp.
When I try to compile it, I get lnk2019 error.
Is there any way to have slots functions in different files?
I am using VC compiler.
Okay, here is extract from the code. (it is quite long)
gui.h

```
#ifndef GUI_H
#define GUI_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "buffer.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "qcustomplot.h"
#include <limits>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>


namespace Ui {
class GUI;
}

class GUI : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GUI(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GUI();
private slots:

    void on_setall_clicked();

    void on_integrace_button_clicked();
    void on_elipsy_button_clicked();
    void on_grafy_button_clicked();

private:
    Ui::GUI *ui;



};
#endif // GUI_H
```

gui.cpp

```
#include "gui.h"
#include "ui_gui.h"

double drand(double from, double to){
    double f = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
    return from + f * (to - from);
}

GUI::GUI(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::GUI)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    srand(time(0));
}

GUI::~GUI()
{
    delete ui;
}
void GUI::on_setall_clicked(){...};
void GUI::on_grafy_button_clicked(){...};
void GUI::on_integrace_button_clicked(){...};
```

elipsy.cpp

```
#include "gui.h"
void GUI::on_elipsy_button_clicked(){...};
```

GUI.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-03-27T09:01:31
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

TARGET = GUI
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        gui.cpp \
    solve_rpn.cpp \
    shunting_yard.cpp \
    qcustomplot.cpp \
    elipsy.cpp \
    grafy.cpp \
    integrace.cpp

HEADERS  += gui.h \
    buffer.h \
    qcustomplot.h

FORMS    += gui.ui
```

And the error code it gives me when i try to compile with the function elipsy_button_clicked() in file other than gui.cpp

```
moc_gui.obj:-1: Chyba:LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl GUI::on_elipsy_button_clicked(void)" (?on_elipsy_button_clicked@GUI@@AEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl GUI::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@GUI@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
debug\GUI.exe:-1: Chyba:LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Well, in case you need the entire sourcecode, I uploaded it
http://seed.gweana.eu/public/GUI.7z

FIXED: The file was ignored by the project, running qmake again solved the issue. Many thanks for the answers :)

Comment: Its very difficult to tell what exactly you have done, you really need to post the code so we can take a look. You basically need to do as you would for a normal c++ class.

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: Please show the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems is that you exported the slot methods to `elipsy.cpp` where on line 14 you try to use: `ui` ... which is defined in `ui_gui.h` included **only** in `gui.cpp`, but forward declared in `gui.h` (which you include of course in `elipsy.cpp`) so this should give you a compilation error. Solution: include `ui_gui.h` in elipsy.cpp. If it doesn't give you a compilation error try to rebuild the application.

Secondly, your `drand` function is defined in `gui.cpp` but not in any header file (easily fixable, modify `gui.h`)...

After fixing these two issues the compilation was ok for me.

So, a few recommendations:

1. Leave the things as they are when comes to Qt ... you will just mess up your head when moving things around.
2. have a separate "module" for utilities, such as `drand`

(PS: Nice app :) )

Comment: 1) That wasn't really a problem, ui itself is part of class GUI, so no need to include ui_gui.h
2) Yep that would be a problem, fixed that
And finally for the issue, compiler just ignored elipsy.cpp no mather what I did. Running qmake again fixed the issue for me... file compiled and I get no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

Generally slots are declared in a header file like,in my Counter.h :

```
    #include <QObject>

    class Counter : public QObject
   {
     Q_OBJECT

    public:
     Counter() { m_value = 0; }

     int value() const { return m_value; }

   public slots:
    void setValue(int value);
 ....
```

Now in Counter.cpp(and it has to include Counter.h), i will define this function like any other normal function.

So in this case everything will work correctly.Does that answers your question?